# makeself running startup script as sourced script

Tags: linux, sh

I was making a self extractable archives using makeself and able to generate and run it.But i have to run the install script as sourced script.

I am seeing an option to pass script argument in makeself command
`makeself.sh [args] archive_dir file_name label startup_script [script_args]`

But none of my arguments are picking up. I have generated the archives using the following command
`makeself.sh ./test ./test.run "sample installer" ./install.sh`

but how can I tell makeself to run install.sh file as sourced script

Comment: What is in the `install.sh` file and why you need to run this file? you want this to use instead, `makeself.sh install.sh`?

Comment: makeself.sh is the command for building the self extractable archives, and install.sh is the starter script of my application.                                                                              syntax: makeself.sh [args] archive_dir file_name label startup_script [script_args]

Comment: `makeself.sh [args] archive_dir file_name label $(startup_script [script_args]) `  did you try this!

Comment: i have tried this..but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Have found out a alternate solution for the issue. Not the actual fix anyway it is working.Instead of calling install.sh as starter script i have added another script which will call the install.sh as sourced script.
`makeself.sh ./test ./test.run "sample installer" ./launcher.sh` and launcher.sh wil contain the following content

Launcher.sh file

```
source ./install.sh
```

Comment: Expecting correct answers, this solution is working ,but appreciate other solutions as well